Where does Microsoft RDP 10 Beta for Mac store its configuration
After I made a full backup of my hard drive using Time Machine and reinstalled macOS, I realized that I had lost all the configurations for Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta.
Where does Microsoft RDP 10 Beta for Mac store its connections and configuration?

Reinstalling macOS shouldn't touch user directories, did you reformat as well? Anyway, preferences usually are in ~/Library/Application Support/NAME-OR-ID-OF-APPLICATION.

Yes, I had to format the entire hard drive and reinstall macOS because it was full.

With some searching, I finally found the path to the configuration file:
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/com.microsoft.rdc.osx.beta

You can see that there are these 5 files and directories
SupportingImages
com.microsoft.appcenter
com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite
com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite-shm
com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite-wal

Copy these files and folders to the new system, reopen the rdp app, and you'll see the connection list from the old configuration!
The username will remain, but the password will be lost, this is unclear why.

The password won't be stored in Application Support, it's probably in the user's Keychain. That might be invalidated because of the restore for some reason.
